# Closed eyes in darkness vs. light

Tags: eye, eye-strain

I've read the closing eyelids helps wet the eyeballs and relieve eye strain at the same time.

Is there a difference between us having closed eyes in complete darkness vs. there's light around us? Does having closed eyes in a illuminated space strain the eyes?

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE, Howie! It might be helpful for you to take the [tour], read the [help] and especially [ask]. Personalised medical advice is off-topic here. With an [edit] that removes personalised info but adds prior research you might salvage this.